# Atomic Pointer dereferencing failure

Tags: c, pointers, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I am trying out a dummy program to understand the usage of memory fences and Atomic pointers. The below code logic has 2 threads in the program, one of which is the consumer of g_ptr->int_ptr->id and another thread mallocs a new memory location, updates the g_ptr->int_ptr memory reference while maintaining the same value of g_ptr->int_ptr->id throughout it's execution cycle. I am aware that a synchronisation could be achieved via locks, which I've avoided for the time-being.

I am quite stumped as to why I would be running into the below Error condition on either ARM/x86_64 based CPUs. Can anyone of you please help me?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

typedef struct _int_st
{
  int id;
} int_st;

typedef struct _dummy_st
{
  int_st * _Atomic int_ptr;   
} dummy_st;

dummy_st *g_ptr;
  
void* func(void* arg)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    
    while(1) {
       int_st * _Atomic tmp_ptr = g_ptr->int_ptr;
       int_st * _Atomic new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int_st));
       new_ptr->id = 2;
       g_ptr->int_ptr = new_ptr;
       atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
       free(tmp_ptr);
    }
  
    // exit the current thread
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
  
void fun()
{
    pthread_t ptid;

    g_ptr = malloc(sizeof(dummy_st));
    g_ptr->int_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int_st));
    g_ptr->int_ptr->id = 2;
    printf("Value of ptr is: %p and size is: %lu \n", g_ptr->int_ptr, sizeof(g_ptr->int_ptr));
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);  

    // Creating a new thread
    pthread_create(&ptid, NULL, &func, NULL);

    int it_num = 0;
    while(1)
    {
       printf("Trying iteration num: %d \n", it_num);
       if (g_ptr->int_ptr->id != 2)
       {
          printf("Error found \n");
          pthread_cancel(ptid);
          printf("Value of ptr is: %p and id is: %d \n", g_ptr->int_ptr, g_ptr->int_ptr->id);
          break;
       }
       it_num++;

    }
 
    printf("This line will be printed"
           " after thread ends\n");
    return;
}
  
// Driver code
int main()
{
    fun();
    return 0;
}`
```

The code Errors out on variable number of iterations, one sample run of which is:

```
Value of ptr is: 0x600003c64040 and size is: 8 
Trying iteration num: 0 
Trying iteration num: 1 
Trying iteration num: 2 
Trying iteration num: 3 
Trying iteration num: 4 
Trying iteration num: 5 
Trying iteration num: 6 
Trying iteration num: 7 
Trying iteration num: 8 
Trying iteration num: 9 
Trying iteration num: 10 
Trying iteration num: 11 
Trying iteration num: 12 
Trying iteration num: 13 
Trying iteration num: 14 
Trying iteration num: 15 
Trying iteration num: 16 
Trying iteration num: 17 
Trying iteration num: 18 
Trying iteration num: 19 
Trying iteration num: 20 
Trying iteration num: 21 
Error found 
Value of ptr is: 0x600003c70000 and id is: 2 
This line will be printed after thread ends
```

Comment: You're reading the value twice. The first time it is not 2, but by the time the printf args are evaluated, it is 2. You should capture it once into a local variable and use that for both the comparison and print.

Comment: Yes I did try that out, the value of g_ptr->int_ptr->id as well as the value of g_ptr->int_ptr is different at the time of comparison failure as compared to what they are at the time of printf execution in the Error found code-block.
Still don't really follow how the main thread sees a stale value of g_ptr->int_ptr despite the use of atomic fence in the other thread as well as using a Atomic pointer

Comment: Why are your local variables `tmp_ptr` and `new_ptr` atomic?  No other thread can ever have a reference to them since you don't take their address.  Assigning to `g_ptr->int_ptr` is an atomic store because *it's* an `_Atomic` variable, regardless of what you assign from.  You don't need to be doing an atomic seq_cst load of your local vars.

Comment: Looks like a use-after-free.  `func()` can be freeing `g_ptr->int_ptr` after `fun` has loaded `g_ptr->int_ptr` but before it accesses the pointed-to memory `g_ptr->int_ptr->id`.  Deallocation is a hard problem for lock-free concurrent data structures, especially if you want to avoid the overhead of atomic RMWs for reference counting.  You must not deallocate something that another thread could possibly still be about to read (or write).

Comment: Also, IDK what you're hoping `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);` will do.  `g_ptr->int_ptr = new_ptr;` is already a `seq_cst` store, which is like `release` but stronger, so it guarantees that readers that see that value of `g_ptr->int_ptr` can see all prior assignments done by this thread.  (happens-before).  But nothing can guarantee that later stores done by this thread won't have overwritten those values if you don't stop modifying stuff.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-fsanitize=thread,undefined`?  Compiling with clang on x86, it detects a heap use-after-free.

Comment: Could it happen that the main thread checks the value of id after the memory allocation with ```int_st * _Atomic new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int_st));```, but before ```new_ptr->id = 2;``` is executed?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think the suggestion you gave above with regard to use-after-free looks most probable. I did try compiling with -fsanitize=thread,undefined and it the problem is never reproducible with it.

Comment: @SouravSen: Right, the extra instrumentation code added to the program (or to malloc to detect use-after-free) happens to prevent the problem.  But look at the very start of the output for the the sanitizer output.  e.g. `./a.out |& less` to pipe stdout and stderr.  It *does* detect a definite bug happening.

Comment: @cforler: No, the `malloc` return value isn't "published" to other threads until `g_ptr->int_ptr = new_ptr;`, which is a release-store and thus guarantees visibility of `new_ptr->id = 2;`.  `new_ptr` and `tmp_ptr` should not be `_Atomic`, that's a distraction; they're private locals not visible to other threads.  It's a use-after-free, as confirmed by clang's sanitizers.